# Using Apache NiFi migrate all tables from Oracle to Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, oracle, apache-nifi

i am trying to use NiFi as ETL to migrate all tables from Oracle to MongoDB (includes one time data movement and incremental updates ). Somehow i managed to create the NiFi Flow for one table. But i need to know how to make it work for all tables? Instead of creating separate flow for all tables, is there a more concise , performance oriented way of doing ?
Pls refer below the flow for one table ? Also is the below flow for one table - is it the right way of doing things ?

[image]

Comment: The processors that you think could be reused for various flows can be placed under a "process group" and can be commonized for different flow, for starters

Comment: Check this [link](https://blog.pythian.com/database-migration-using-apache-nifi/)